# A pop-up was on my screen and said I had a virus!

Tags: hardware, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge, antivirus

I was searching up fun computer games to play when a message came up saying I have a virus and I should download this weird app and give it a lot of my personal information including phone number and email.

I'm scared this is a scam. What do I do??

Comment: You must know that in Android a website cannot know more than what Chrome would permit it to know, and there is no way a website can detect the installed apps or the running programs in your device, scan them on-the-fly and flag the malware. **Such pop-ups are always a scam.**

Answer (score 5):

Congrats! You won 10 bottles of snake oil if you're lucky.

Honestly: this has two very clear indicators of being scam:

1. There are no viruses on Android. And even if there were, how should that website know?
2. Asking you to download an app via their specific link to fix {whatever}. If you do so, *then* you are in trouble.

Ignore that message (close the tab of your browser were it appeared), but remember that website – to never visit it again.

Comment: _There are no viruses on Android_ - I doubt that

Comment: @msrd0 name one. And don't confuse "virus" with "malware": a virus is malware, but malware not necessarily a virus (as an apple is a fruit but a fruit not always an apple). The speciality of a virus is self-replication. All Android malware I know of always requires user interaction (or the manufacturer pre-installing it). Though those who sell you their "Anti-Virus" want to believe you otherwise, of course ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the the pop-up with the (fake) countdown timer on it, which I've seen before, then just know that it doesn't have malware, and neither do any other pop-ups. They're just pieces of scareware (Advertisements designed to scare the victims into a reaction, like downloading an app).  If it'll make you feel better, then feel free to download a (legit) anti-malware app on the Play Store and perform a scan with that. My personal recommendation is Malwarebyte's Android app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.malwarebytes.antimalware&hl=en .